# A problem about the matrix equation $x^HAx+x^HB\bar{x}+x^TCx=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be three $m\times m$ ($m\geq1$) complex constant matrices. For any $m$-dimensional complex-variable vector $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_m)^T\in\mathbb{C}^m$, we denote its conjugate by
$$\bar{x}=(x_1^*,x_2^*,...,x_m^*)^T$$
and conjugate transpose
$$x^H=(x_1^*,x_2^*,...,x_m^*).$$
If the three matrices $A$, $B$, and $C$ satisfy
$$x^HAx+x^HB\bar{x}+x^TCx=0,\quad\text{for all }x\in\mathbb{C}^m,$$
prove that
$$x^HAx+x^HB\bar{x}+x^TCx
=x^HAx+\frac{1}{2}x^H(B+B^T)\bar{x}+\frac{1}{2}x^T(C+C^T)x,\quad\text{for all }x\in\mathbb{C}^m.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^H B\overline{x}$ is a scalar. Therefore
$$x^H B\overline{x} = (x^H B\overline{x})^T = x^H B^T\overline{x}.$$
Same goes for $x^TCx$.